# Provided schema version 1 is less than last set version 0 in React native

Tags: react-native, realm

Although the question looks like a duplicate with another existing question, I could not get it through. In order to change the type of one property for a schema, I added the `versionSchema` as required, (e.g., `let realm = new Realm({schemaVersion:1, schema:[PersonSchema]})`, but it shows:

> Provided schema version 1 is less than last set version 0

I tried to both deleting the added sentence and editing the sentence, but it shows the same error as though it's already remembered it.

How can I fix this?

Comment: I had the same problem, but it's a little bit complicated, mine was that I was accessing realm before setting the migration options, but it's better if you post your code

Comment: I think I have fixed the problem, cuz there are two js files involving the realm, and i used "let realm = new Realm({schemaVersion:1, schema:[PersonSchema]})" for the both files, and it works.

Comment: OK, but I'm not sure if it's a good practice to instantiate realm in two places, but anyway goodluck

Comment: BTW, Have you fixed this problem. Do you need any help?

Comment: yes, thanx I fixed it a long time ago, but I do remember banging my head against the wall a couple of times ;-)

Answer (score 1):

The problem can occur if your database is set to readOnly. I changed that to false and the migration block started getting called.

Answer (score 0):

In AppDelegate.m :

```
#import <Realm/RLMRealmConfiguration.h>
```

//Inside your [AppDelegate didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:]

```
//Realm detect new properties and removed properties
    RLMRealmConfiguration *config = [RLMRealmConfiguration defaultConfiguration];
    // Set the new schema version. This must be greater than the previously used
    // version (if you've never set a schema version before, the version is 0).
    config.schemaVersion = 1;

    // Set the block which will be called automatically when opening a Realm with a
    // schema version lower than the one set above

    config.migrationBlock = ^(RLMMigration *migration, uint64_t oldSchemaVersion) {
        // We haven’t migrated anything yet, so oldSchemaVersion == 0
        if (oldSchemaVersion < 1) {
            // Nothing to do!
            // Realm will automatically detect new properties and removed properties
            // And will update the schema on disk automatically
        }
    };

// Tell Realm to use this new configuration object for the default Realm

    [RLMRealmConfiguration setDefaultConfiguration:config];

// Now that we've told Realm how to handle the schema change, opening the file
// will automatically perform the migration

    [RLMRealm defaultRealm];
```